# ASP.NET core db2 connection issue

Tags: .net, db2

I am trying to connect IBM db2 server in VS 2017 in ASP.NET Core application but it is throwing error as

> Unable to load DLL 'db2app64.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
>
> at IBM.Data.DB2.Core.UnsafeNativeMethods.DB232.SQLFreeConnAttribsADONET(DB2SQLGetConnAttribsADONETParams& pParam)
>   at IBM.Data.DB2.Core.ConnSettingsFromXmlConfig.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
>      at IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2ConnPool.ReplaceConnectionStringParms(DB2Connection connection, String szValue, DB2ConnSettings& pSettings, DB2ConnSettingsInternal& > pSettingsInternal,   Boolean bAttach, Boolean pushDownStrAppended)
>   at IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2Connection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
>   at DB2.Controllers.CheckController.Index() in D:\Sample Projects\CodeProjects\DB2\DB2\Controllers\CheckController.cs:line 26
>   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__27.MoveNext()

My connection string is:

```
var mycon = "Server=10.64.0.30;Database=Gbgeorr;User Id=FORMSCAPE;Password=******";

DB2Connection db2 = new DB2Connection(mycon);   //error throwing here 

if (db2.IsOpen == false)
  db2.Open();
```

Comment: what version of .net core are you using? 1.0, 1.1, 2.0 etc. Have you downloaded the correct driver from nugget e.g. `https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBM.Data.DB2.Core/`

Comment: Thank you bilpor,i am using aspnet core 1.1 ,i already installed ibm.data.db2.core 1.1 version, at the time of passing connection string throwing error as above.

Comment: have you followed this link on how to add the connection `https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/96960515-2ea1-4391-8170-b0515d08e4da/entry/Getting_Started_on_ADO_Net_Core_web_application_to_access_IBM_Data_Servers?lang=en`

Comment: No, i followed this link http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/adonet/db2-connection-strings-in-adonet,

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/96960515-‌​2ea1-4391-8170-b0515‌​d08e4da/entry/Gettin‌​g_Started_on_ADO_Net‌​_Core_web_applicatio‌​n_to_access_IBM_Data‌​_Servers?lang=en   this link doesn't have anything, it shows the page as Oops — that's not right!
Sorry, unless you really were hoping to find our 404 message, the page you were looking
for has been moved or deleted

Comment: The link that you have given above relate to non-.net core connection settings, They are different for .net core. take a look at this link [linking db2](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=9a107d00-d814-440c-b438-faa4d020ae1a&ps=25) there might be something from here that you can take

Comment: Have you added the Core DB2 driver's bin path to your PATH variable?

Comment: DId you fix it?

Comment: same issue here..